# geth keeps quitting

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, poa, ethstats

I am running a `geth` node in a docker container for a POA private blockchain. The version of `geth` is `Geth/v1.8.14-unstable-35fcd2f4/linux-amd64/go1.10.3`. It is started using the command

```
--networkid 1337 --cache 512 --syncmode="full" --txpool.accountslots 128 --txpool.globalslots 32768 --txpool.accountqueue 512 --txpool.globalqueue 8192 --port 30303 --maxpeers 50 --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi "eth,personal,web3,net" --ws --wsport 8546 --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsorigins "*" --wsapi "eth,web3,net" --ethstats "id:pass@url" --bootnodes enode://xxxxxx@167.99.00.00:30303
```

**Problem:** `geth` keeps crashing every few days. The logs always show a ping error message as the last lines before it shut down:

> Stats server pinger seems to have died

How can we get more info about the reason for crashing? Why is it crashing?

```
...
INFO [08-16|02:41:44.378] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x0949e4707e310497adfad86e054b0f251d699c9ccc46e49b298eb71027dd0dd5 recipient=0xa70f993D5Dd72DD8567b3da7eD1A945A39Ab44b1
INFO [08-16|02:50:44.948] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x79ba994fad6b0989489c5f526072afb7ab073b073eb05740aed7d9994c144224 recipient=0xa70f993D5Dd72DD8567b3da7eD1A945A39Ab44b1
INFO [08-16|02:55:33.242] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=2711 accounts=2
INFO [08-16|02:58:46.335] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x43febddcdf4dda52886a8357561a6c45b73fdb2d98ddaf31bdf38f179e347cb5 recipient=0xa70f993D5Dd72DD8567b3da7eD1A945A39Ab44b1
WARN [08-16|02:59:12.260] Full stats report failed                 err="ping timed out"
WARN [08-16|02:59:16.162] Stats server pinger seems to have died
```

3 other `geth` nodes running in docker containers did not crash. All nodes were connected to the ethstats service. All geth node run on the same hardware: Digitalocean with 1GB memory and 2GB swap.

Comment: this log message  is from ethstats service, did you try to disable it?

Comment: @Nulik I believe I have ethstats running all the time. 2 sealer nodes and a boot node have been running fine, though they are on an earlier version of geth `2e0391ea`

Comment: also what do you mean by `crash`, for me , when crash occurs, the stack trace of failed goroutine is printed and I don't see it in your logs.

Comment: @Nulik By crash, I mean that the docker container that `geth` was running in simply exits

Comment: in that case, maybe it is not even `geth`s issue, but an issue with docker container

Comment: @Nulik Good point, might be a docker issue. Not sure how to troubleshoot in this case

Comment: I suggest to monitor memory & swap use

Comment: @Nulik All geth docker containers are running on their own Digitalocean droplet with 1GB memory and 2GB swap. Does this sound sufficient? I'll be monitoring mem/swap now. Is there a good way to log the mem/swap so we know their values at the time of crash?

Comment: You have a private chain, so I can't know your requirements. On Linux I am using `vmstat` , `iotop` and `top` to monitor what happens. You can create a C program to spawn `geth` as child process and monitor it's memory usage.  However there probably `supervision` scripts available somewhere on the net for this task.